# Php and SQL issued with foreach

Tags: php, sql, foreach

I have this following warning :

> Warning: Invalid argument supplied for foreach()

Because my function return `false` , but i don't understand why it returns `false`

There is the function :

```
function getPlayerId($pseudo){

    $bdd=getBDD();

    $thisPlayerId= $bdd->query('SELECT users.id FROM users WHERE users.pseudo='.$pseudo);

    return $thisPlayerId;

}
```

and there is the call :

```
$thisPlayerID = getPlayerId("test");

//var_dump(isset($thisPlayerID));

foreach ($thisPlayerID as $r3){
    echo $r['id'].'<br>';
}
```

Comment: After executing the `query`, you haven't fetched the results.

Comment: Change foreach to this **foreach ($thisPlayerID->fetch_array(MYSQLI_ASSOC) as $r3){**

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Your function returns `false` because the query is invalid and fails:

```
'SELECT users.id FROM users WHERE users.pseudo='.$pseudo
```

`$pseudo` is a string so it should have been escaped and quoted. Before PDO and mysqli.

Now you should use a prepared statement:

```
'SELECT users.id FROM users WHERE users.pseudo=?'
```

and bind your value to the placeholder.

As both mysqli and PDO return objects that implement `Traversable`, you can loop over the resulting object without any problems to get your rows.

Comment: thanks , i used this way is that ok ?

    $thisPlayerId= $bdd->prepare('SELECT users.id FROM users WHERE users.pseudo=:pseudonyme');


    $thisPlayerId->execute(array('pseudonyme'=> $pseudo));

Comment: @LaurentOuttan That's perfect if you are using PDO. Mysqli doesn't support named placeholders. Does it work?

Answer (score 0):

If you try to solve it with an additional empty check for the `$thisPlayerID` variable you won't get that error:

```
//var_dump(isset($thisPlayerID));
if(!empty($thisPlayerID))
{
    foreach ($thisPlayerID as $r3){
        echo $r3['id'].'<br>';
    }
}
```

Comment: Please elaborate your answer. It gives more understanding